# Apache2 VirtualHost SSL isn't working

Tags: debian, ssl, apache2

I have debian 8 VPS, with apache2. I have some website, that is on 1803 port of my server. I need https, for some works I am doing on this website. I do not have domain for it. So i tried to create Open SSl certificate

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```

Then in apache2.conf I wrote this

```
<VirtualHost *:1803>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite/frontend/web"
    ServerName mysite.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

But now as I am trying to access to myip:1803 it is just endlessly loading. Chrome is saying "waiting for myip". If I remove SSL, it works fine. What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Hi Igor, you should try to connect to **https**://hostname:1803/

Comment: @MichaelHampton But i do not have registered domain, i am accessing to website only by ip address and port. Or what do you mean?

Comment: You could also use the IP address. But the important part is `https://` e.g. `https://203.0.113.187:1803/`